# Sort vector of integers in specific (custom) order

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a vector of integers let's say from 1 to 3 (can be more):

```
x <- sample(1:3, 10, replace=T)

[1] 1 3 1 2 2 1 3 2 3 2
```

If I sort `x` I'll get

```
sort(x)
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

But I need 2s to go first, then 1s, then 3s.

```
[1] 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 3 3 3
```

So, if I have a vector `y = c(2, 1, 3)`, how I can use it for sorting order?

And actually I need not the values itself, but the index of sorted values in original vector, as I get from `order` function.

Comment: Are the numbers always from 1 to N?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple remapping of the values works:

```
x <- sample(1:3, 10, replace=T)
x
 [1] 2 3 1 1 3 2 2 3 3 2
order(c(2,1,3)[x])
 [1]  1  6  7 10  3  4  2  5  8  9
```

Answer (score 8):

A somewhat convoluted option:

```
x[order(factor(x,levels = c(2,1,3)))]
```

or obviously, just the `order` call for just the indices.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I think `as.integer` call in not necessary. Right?